# Making a Stand-Alone Java EXE File

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

I'm currently a student at a high school, and I found a game programming competition for a club called  FBLA. I had a few questions about the competition, and so I emailed them.

I made a post earlier on Computer Science Stack Exchange, where you can view [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/31999/isnt-software-needed-from-programs-to-run/32001?noredirect=1#comment64707_32001).

Now after receiving feedback from the question, someone commented that I should post my next question on this website.

---

My question is that how would I be able to package a Java JAR file with the native libraries, and then create an EXE out of it, so it will be a stand alone?

In my theory, I would have to create the jar, and put the required native files when a person installs java on their machine, into that JAR file, and then I can use a program such as FatJar or JSmooth.

If I'm wrong, or how I could understand a bit more on how jars are ran, it would help considerably.

---

**Update Nov. 8, 2014**
I finally got back around to messing with it, and I downloaded Launch4j. I set up and did everything with it, and I make an executable, which contains all of java's core native files. I uninstalled all of my programs dealing with java, and when I went to run it, it still required java.

*Once again to state what I need to happen:*
What needs to happen is the executable will be able to run even if there's not any version of Java installed on the judge's computer.

Answer (score 3):

I would reccomend you use launch4j. http://launch4j.sourceforge.net

I've used it for some larger projects and it worked very well.

It can encapsulate your jar, dependencies and even a JRE into a windows in executable. It has a GUI or you can run from the command line.

Comment: It's been a while since I've messed with this issue, and I just recently messed with it. I downloaded Launch4j, and I ran everything. I uninstalled every bit of java from my computer to test a simple application (just opens a JFrame), and I see all of the files from my Java directory in the executable, but it's still requiring a java version, did I do something wrong?

Comment: I remember having some issues with it doing a similar thing when not embedding a JVM and it had to do with the min/max java version config values. Specifying the min as the version I had and max as a hypothetical java 9 worked around it. Not sure if that is the same issue you are seeing or not but if you didn't specify a min and max version I would try that.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Packr, created by libGDX team: https://github.com/libgdx/packr

Answer (score 0):

To make your jar executable, you specify the main class of your application, any extra jar files it may require and so on in the jar's manifest file:

```
Main-Class: MyAppMain
Class-Path: MyLib.jar
```

Then you use the jar utility from the Java SDK to package your classes and resource files, specifying the m option and the name of your manifest file:

```
jar cvfm MyApp.jar MyApp.mf *.class *.gif
```

This will result in the creation of `MyApp.jar`. Now, if you type

```
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

the Java launcher will read the manifest from `MyApp.jar`, place that file *and* `MyLib.jar` on classpath and invoke the main method from the class `MyAppMain`.

Now, if your Java app needs native libraries, you also need to specify the `java.library.path` property pointing to the directory(ies) holding those:

```
java -Djava.library.path=.\bin -jar MyApp.jar
```

For more info and alternative solutions, refer to [my article](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html).